# Is there a good radio-like audio streaming solution for node.js?

Tags: node.js, streaming, audio-streaming, html5-audio

I'm looking for something to stream audio like radio (playing continuously and clients can join in the middle of a song) with node.js. Is there any node.js module (which I couldn't find)or anything else that I can use along with node.js to achieve this? Is this possible at all with node.js? If not, what do you recommend to use otherwise? (though, I prefer node.js) It's ok for me to use HTML5 Audio API and I don't care about IE support.

Thanks.

Comment: Look here: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/audio

Comment: and here: http://pedromtavares.wordpress.com/2012/12/28/streaming-audio-on-the-web-with-nodejs/

Comment: @RobertHarvey this sounds good: https://npmjs.org/package/audiostream but I can make this myself without any module. What I want is when the next client connects he/she can listen from the exact time the song is playing. But I will look further into it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the other link looks more like what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is entirely possible.  I am hosting internet radio on Node.js at the moment.

All you have to do is take the raw stream data from the encoder and send it via HTTP to any connected clients.  The clients are good about synching up with the stream, so you don't have to worry about aligning to frames or anything.

Comment: How do you handle the Serverside Playlist ? Any examples would be lovely, please.

Comment: @daslicht That's a different problem.  I use VLC for this, since it can handle any input file I could possibly have.  There is other auto-DJ software available that even does the encoding for you.  I haven't used any of them recently, so I can't make a specific recommendation.

Comment: I am not looking for an autodj, since real DJs mixes are simply better :) Do you like to share some code how to use VLC as input ?please. I am just looking for a source which can play and loop long prerecorded dj mixes while still having single song infos (cue sheet?), related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962666/nodejs-server-side-playlist-radio-without-shoutcast, like to help me on this topic ? please

Comment: When using VLC as source, how to deal with Metadata ? Is there a way to get them from VLC either ?

Comment: @daslicht Yes, you can connect to VLC on a separate interface, such as HTTP.  See this question for more details:  http://superuser.com/q/583251/48624

Comment: Thank you very much, that looks promising. Do you have any example or suggestion how to get audio from vlc into node, please?

Comment: @daslicht I actually use a virtual audio loopback cable and DirectShow in FFmpeg to capture and encode.  It's not necessary to do all of this... you might find it more efficient if you can get VLC to use STDIO for its output.  This should be possible, but my project evolved from another player so I dropped in VLC as-is.

Comment: i see, I am looking for a linux server side way to solve this :/

Comment: @daslicht Yes, just use VLC with standard output as a child process to Node.js, and pipe the STDOUT stream to FFmpeg to encode it.  VLC can also encode media, but usually I'm needing to encode many codecs at the same time.

Comment: @bard: I dont know how this works, do you have any suggestion or examples please? I looked up the vlc cli docs but I dont know where to start

Comment: @daslicht `vlc -vvv --color http://websiteaddress.mp3 --sout '#std{mux=ts,access=file,dst=-}'` https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=39722  VLC (and FFmpeg) have very complicated command lines.  Basically if you use `-` for an input file or output file, you're using STDIO.

Comment: @Bard: Thank you very much for your help! How would I receive the the vlc output in node? createReadStream() ?

Comment: @daslicht STDIO streams are available on the child process.  http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdout

Comment: Do you know any alternative which supports cuesheets or which returns the current playback position?
VLC has a bug which results into not passed metadata ::
https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=14476&start=40