# Are there any audio streaming solutions for flask?

Tags: python, streaming, flask, audio-streaming, html5-audio

With reference to this question:

[Is there a good radio-like audio streaming solution for node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224808/is-there-a-good-radio-like-audio-streaming-solution-for-node-js)

are there any flask modules which will help with building a streaming server for HTML5 audio?

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure if we have any flask-modules for audio, i recently found this article about audio streaming and it may be useful to you.

[pypix.com/python/create-simple-music-streaming-app-flask/](http://pypix.com/python/create-simple-music-streaming-app-flask/)

Comment: The link is dead.