# NodeJS basedRadio (without ShoutCast)

Tags: node.js, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I like to create a radio Station which is based on NodeJS while *not* using ShoutCast.

### NodeJS based Playlist

Currently I have managed to steam an audio file to the browser, but I don't know **how to create a server side Playlist** which continuously keeps "playing" the current song and restart it once the end has been reached.

thats my current approach:

```
'use strict';
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var mm = require('musicmetadata');
var ID3 = require('id3');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var stream;

function startPlaylist() {
    stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/AnsolasChill_loop.mp3', {
        start: 0
    }); //10130000
   /*
      * Start serverside "Playback" here.
      * Restart Playlist once the end of the song has been reached
    */

}
startPlaylist(); // Start Server Side Playlist once the Server starts.


app.get('/', function(req, res) {


    /*
       * get current playback postion of playlist 
       * start stream from current playback position  
    */
    
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'audio/mpeg');
    stream.pipe(res);

    // Events
    stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
      console.log('data: got %d bytes of data', chunk.length);
    })

    stream.on('end', function() {
        console.log('there will be no more data.');
        stream = null;
        stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/AnsolasChill_loop.mp3', {
            start: 0
        });
    
    });

    stream.on('readable', function() {
        var chunk;
        while (null !== (chunk = stream.read())) {
          //console.log(i,' readable:', chunk.length);
        }
    });

});

app.listen(3000);
```

---

[edit]

### VLC as Playlist ?

Just found this thread:
Related: [Is there a good radio-like audio streaming solution for node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224808/is-there-a-good-radio-like-audio-streaming-solution-for-node-js/16239355?noredirect=1#comment35066445_16239355)

Brad told me that he use VLC as source for his node based Radio.

So I assume that he pipes the output from VLC to Node?
How to deal with Metadata ?
Is there a way to get them from VLC either ?
Or at least is it possible to get the Current Song ID or some other way to identify the current playing song?
An example would be very nice.

---

Any constructive help is welcome :)

Comment: I'm doing something similar, I'm using the shoutcast protocol, so the only thing that changes is a URI to the file. Because you are streaming directly from a single file, in your function `stream.on('end',callback)` you need to point to another one. Commonly, you would store your available files in a database and chose a subset from your table as your playlist.

Comment: Check this library out, it queues up your files to form a playlist https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-queuestream

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not looking for a simple List which gets played back from the start to the end once a client starts playback. I am looking for a Player which keeps 'playing' even if no client is connected so that the clients will have a Radio like experience. idea?

Comment: For anyone who may read this, try out https://www.npmjs.com/package/queuestream.
It's old but it works.